# ASP.NET how to hide template field control based on another template field value in GridView

Tags: asp.net

here my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="_gvPLCs" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
                                CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="_dsPLCs" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal" 
                                onrowcommand="_gvPLCs_RowCommand" onrowdatabound="_gvPLCs_RowDataBound">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbnView" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" 
                                                CommandName="view" Text="View manual"></asp:LinkButton>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PLCName" SortExpression="PLCName">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PLCName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <EditItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PLCName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                        </EditItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PLCManual" SortExpression="PLCManual">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PLCManual") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <EditItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PLCManual") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                        </EditItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LabName" SortExpression="LabName">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LabName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <EditItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LabName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                        </EditItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MachineName" SortExpression="MachineName">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MachineName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <EditItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MachineName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                        </EditItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MaxAllowedToResDay" 
                                        SortExpression="MaxAllowedToResDay">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MaxAllowedToResDay") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <EditItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" 
                                                Text='<%# Bind("MaxAllowedToResDay") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                        </EditItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                                <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
                                <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            </asp:GridView>
```

code behind:

```
    protected void _gvPLCs_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        return;
    if (e.Row.Cells[2].Text == "&nbsp;")
    {
        LinkButton lbnview = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lbnView");
        lbnview.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

this doesn't work with me..plz help

what i need is : when there is no a manual;the view manual link disappear

i tested it using this code :

```
  if (e.Row.Cells[2].Text == string.Empty)
    {
        LinkButton lbnview = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lbnView");
        lbnview.Visible = false;
    }
```

but it always give me "" and always manaul field disappears

Comment: Is testing for "&nbsp;"  really what you want?  What if the string is "" or null?  Try hard-coding a something to see if it's the test or the actual hiding code that is failing.

Comment: @Steve: i editd my code>>plz have a look

Comment: @Ragaei Any luck with this one?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbnView" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="view" Text="View manual" Visible='<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Bind("PLCName").ToString()) %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```